# What are the mutual auth checks done by node.js tls module?

Tags: node.js, tls1.2, mutual-authentication

I've copied the text from the reference manual from [here](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_checkserveridentity_hostname_cert)

> Verifies the certificate cert is issued to hostname
>
> This function can be overwritten by providing alternative function as
>   part of the options.checkServerIdentity option passed to
>   tls.connect(). The overwriting function can call
>   tls.checkServerIdentity() of course, to augment the checks done with
>   additional verification.

So, my question is what are the checks done in tls.checkServerIdentity() to verify certificate ? does it include dns resolution of host present in request ? I'm doing a mutual auth tls and would like to do dns resolution of host if its not done already in the tls.checkServerIdentity()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by looking at the source code of checkServerIdentity [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/a7c13cf53daa7ca024f46f70322bba5cc13f4a40/lib/tls.js#L207)

It checks SAN and CN fields of certificate to see a match of hostname.